# AC Vent - Unidentified Object

Tags: bathroom, mold, fungus

Can anyone confirm if this is mold? I’m also extremely curious what the chunk of UGO (unidentified gross object) is that is sticking out. It’s not well lit, there’s another larger object that is on the first row of openings and right in the middle (by the lever to open/close vents.

This vent is in the bathroom so is likely candidate for mold growth although it’s never been an issue in this house as far as I know. I checked other vents and don’t see anything with exception of the bedroom
vent which, I believe, is the next vent down the line from the bathroom vent.

Bonus points if anyone has an educated guess on the type, or group/family of molds/mildews this growth is? And tips on how to proceed :)

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks time more like hair held in place by accumulated crud. Dismount the faceplate, wash with dish detergent,  dry, reinstall, forget it unless it rapidly reappears.

Comment: Looks to me like some patches of rust in some areas and some clumps of dust that's been spray-painted over.